# Как записать логи ffmpeg в файл

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

ffmpeg код вне баш скрипта работает отлично. Почему то когда пытаюсь записать логи в файл через `2>` - ругается `Unable to find a suitable output format for '2>'`

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd="ffmpeg -re -i "xx.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/home5 2> /var/log/nginx/home5.log"
$cmd
until $cmd ; do
        echo "restarting ffmpeg command..."
        sleep 2
done
```

Comment: Потому что 2> запихнуто в одну строку вместе с остальной  коммандой

Comment: ну а как правильно сделать?

Comment: `typeset -r cmd=("ffmeg" "-re" "-i" ...` потом `"${cmd[@]}" 2> "/var/log/nginx/home5.log"`

Comment: можно полный листинг?